# The most convenient pattern for XHR and route change in React/Redux application

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm working on a React+Redux application, and I have search functionality in it. As for UI it is quite similar to any other search engine - there is a Home page, and a Search Result page.

So to get search results, I have an action `requestSearch`, which returns an object with action type and data. It is captured by redux-saga, where I make a request to the API, process the response and dispatch new action with the search results, which is captured by a reducer. But it is not the question.

The questions is, where do I initiate the whole thing? Also, what is the best place for routing here (react-router v3), where to change the route? I'm asking about any good pattern, because obviously, I'm missing something important here. 
So far I tried 2 ways to implement that:

- call `requestSearch` actions on search form submit and then change
  the route with history.push();
- change the route and call
  `requestSearch` from Search Result page container.

I'm not satisfied with both of these solutions. 
Will appreciate any help, suggestions or criticism.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't change route?

Comment: @elmeister nice try :p

Answer (score 1):

> •call requestSearch actions on search form submit and then change the
>   route with history.push();

OK, it is possible to approach the decision of this task on the other hand and to consider several moments. First, if you use react-router, it isn't necessary to do direct calls like history.push any more, instead it is necessary to use konsistenty and to cause push function from https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux there where it is necessary.

Secondly, in redux-saga there is an access to push action into store - in current case it will be `react-router-redux` action `push` with appropriate URL:

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'
yield put(push('/foo'))
```

Setup your store as following:

```
import { routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux'

// Apply the middleware to the store
const middleware = routerMiddleware(browserHistory)
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(middleware)
)

// Dispatch from anywhere like normal.
store.dispatch(push('/foo'))
```